# How can I make a bash script that determines if a program is already running

Tags: bash, python

There is a python program I am making, and I am planning to have it launch via a bash script. However the program acts badly when the computer tries to launch it twice. Since I really only need this program to launch once, how do I tell if the program is already running or not.

Comment: Why launch a python app with a bash script?? Put the pid check inside the python app. There are existing questions that cover this: [single instance of program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/380870/175584) or [Check if python script is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/788411/175584)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your bash script is called *my_script.sh*, then add this at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
for pid in $(pidof -x my_script.sh); do
    if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
        exit 1
    fi 
done
python python_app.py
```

It will list all the PIDs related to *my_script.sh* and verify if they are the same of the process we are currently running. If not, then exits the script.

Comment: This seemed to work, but there seems to be syntax error as it said the command was not found, and that command was the pid of the script.

Comment: @needoriginalname Maybe you need to install `pidof`.

Comment: pidof is installed, otherwise it wouldn't have gotten the pid of the script.

Comment: @needoriginalname I've just tested on *Debian Wheezy* and *Centos 6* and it's working on both of them.

Comment: No, wait my bad. I forgot a space between the [ and the $.

I am not used to bash scripting, sorry.

Answer (score 12):

One way would be to log the PID of the python process in, say, `/var/run` then the bash script could see if the file with that PID exists and if it does if that PID is still running.

Another possibility would be to use `pgrep` to see if the process is running if there is a unique enough part of the name (python is likely too common to use, but the py script itself would probably work).  For example:

```
if pgrep -f "python yourScript.py" &>/dev/null; then
    echo "it is already running"
    exit
else
    python yourScript.py
fi
```

assuming `yourScript.py` will daemonize itself or something like that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908610/how-to-get-pid-of-background-process could be useful to get the pid of the subscript launched and store it in `/var/run`

Answer (score 0):

try using ps -ef

```
  #!/bin/bash
  export me=`basename $0`
  if [[ -n $(ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | grep -v $me) ]]; then      
     echo "the program is running";
  else     
    echo "not running"; 
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A lock file might be a more elegant way of doing it. When your program launches, it checks for a lock and if there is one, it stops. If there is isn't one, it creates one and carries on running.

It would also be a useful way of you telling how long the program has been running by the time on the lock file.

I was researching this the other day and found this post: [The best way to ensure only 1 copy of bash script is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715137/the-best-way-to-ensure-only-1-copy-of-bash-script-is-running)